# What does 'insofar as' mean?

Tags: meaning

> The first option tends to follow the classic addiction model, **insofar as** [in that?] the foods that are known to trigger the most intense cravings are eliminated indefinitely. [National Post]
>
> The depiction of sex in the show is arguably one of its distinctive aspects, and cheesy only **insofar as** sex is fundamentally absurd. [The Atlantic]

I can't understand these sentences. I've read dictionary, it says "insofar as" means "to the extent that", then I replace "insofar as" with "to the extent that" in my mind but I still can't understand. Could someone put this sentence in another way?

Can **'insofar as'** be replaced with **'to the extent that'**? And what is the difference between **'insofar as'**, **'as far as'** and **'so far as'**? I'm so confused.

Comment: Have you looked it up in a dictionary, like this one? https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/insofar-as If that doesn't answer your question, please edit your question to explain exactly what you don't understand.

Comment: @JavaLatte I've checked it in dictionary,  I replace this phrase with "to the extent that" in my mind but I still can't understand.  Could you put this sentence in another way? Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you please edit your question to provide a link to the complete article? I have no idea what "the classic addition model" is, and that's important to understand the first sentence. I don't see a problem with the second sentence, "the depiction of sex in the show ... is cheesy [in bad taste] only to the same extent as sex is absurd."